# Table relationship process for tables that need data that has not been submitted yet

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a form that uploads pdf documents to a table, let's say 'tbl_documents_one'. I am using Uploadify to upload those documents which is not a problem for now.

The problem is that I'm new to PHP and am lagging a bit on best practices.

What would be the best practice to link the current form's table to the documents table. Current form is not submitted yet and the documents would be submitted beforehand, I'd like to make it so that that record of current form would be linked to the documents it contains.
Any way to set up the documents table and the id that would link these two tables and what if the document records are added but never given a proper link or updated.

I'm actually using an Codeigniter 2 rig.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution for that as far as i understand that you are uploading documents and than submitting form. When you upload documents create a table for these documents which will contain id and nam e and link of that uploaded file.

```
documents : id , title(of document)  , link , status
```

Than in the form fetch this table data and let user select one document for each form. Your query should contain a flag here Status. if status is set to 1 it means this has already been linked to a form. The default value for this status should be 0. Than query should fatch all those records where status is 0.

Comment: Yes! But what if there are numerous forms open at the same time submitting the documents. Wouldn't then all the forms will have documents in the document table with status 0?

I was thinking a unique id that would link each form with its set of documents, I don't have much idea how to do it though.


Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: uploading a file with each form is too simple. Why can't you do this?

Comment: First of all, I have a form that may upload many files (jquery 'add file' buttons adds a div to the form that allows to add a file with its title and other details). The file itself is uploaded immediately with uploadify, it goes into a table. So the user uploads adds as many files as he likes, then fill the main form and submits that. I wouldn't have an ID as long the user hasn't submitted the main form. There are many users and there is a possibility that 2 or more users can be filling the same type of form at the same time so 'status' idea only might not be enough.

Comment: Also I have to restrict the user to only be able to upload pdf documents which is the main reason I'm using Uploadify.

Comment: i had recently the same situation. i used ajax upload while i was on the form. Than i had some hidden input feilds. When upload through ajas done i fill the hidden field with the uploaded file info. when i save the file i was able the save the upload file info with the form. Does that make sense to you.